# Python script runs fine from terminal but crashes when run from crontab

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, cron

I have a simple python script that takes screenshots of a computer that is running Ubuntu. I want it to run automatically on startup, so I put `@reboot python3 /bin/program.py` in the non-sudo version of crontab.

The program works fine when run from terminal, but gives the error `pyscreenshot.err.FailedBackendError`. I put it in a try loop, and had it write all exceptions to a file, and that's how I found the error message, "All backends failed."

It has something to do with the program 'pyscreenshot' not working correctly.

```py
import pyscreenshot as screen
import os
from numpy import random
from time import sleep
from os.path import expanduser


TMP_SCREEN_PATH = expanduser('~') + '/.UE/tmp.png'
LOG_FILE_PATH = expanduser('~') + '/.UE/log.txt'
GRAB_DELAY_RANGE = (1, 10)


def screenshot(save_path=TMP_SCREEN_PATH):
    img = screen.grab()
    img.save(save_path)


def delay(delay_range):
    sleep_time = random.randint(delay_range[0], delay_range[1])
    print(f"Sleeping for {sleep_time} seconds")
    sleep(sleep_time)


def main():
    try:
        while True:
            screenshot()
            delay(GRAB_DELAY_RANGE)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Nope")
        main()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        with open(LOG_FILE_PATH, 'a') as f:
            f.write(str(type(e))+str(e)+'\n')
        sleep(5)
        main()

f = open(LOG_FILE_PATH, 'w+')
f.write('Startup')
f.close()
main()
```

I need one of the following solutions:

1. Simply fix the problem
2. Another way to run a program at startup
3. A different module to take screenshots with

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user that the cron job runs as is also logged in on the console (you mention a reboot, so I'm guessing that you have enabled autologin), then your cron job might work if you also add:

```
os.environ["DISPLAY"] = ":0"
```

This worked for me on Ubuntu in a test using cron and a simplified version of your script:

```
import os
import pyscreenshot as screen
os.environ["DISPLAY"] = ":0"
img = screen.grab()
img.save("/tmp/test.png")
```

If it doesn't work for you, then you might also have to try setting the value of the `XAUTHORITY` environment variable to the value found in the environment of the user's interactive processes, which could be extracted using the `psutil` package, but let's hope this isn't needed.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate you taking the time to figure this out for me. Would you be willing to explain what that is doing/why it works? You don't have to but I'd appreciate it. Thanks again.

Comment: @l-d It is an X client application, so it needs the `DISPLAY` variable set in order to know which X server to talk to. `:0` is used for the default display on the local machine. This variable is set automatically in a windowing environment but would not normally be set in the cron environment.